# Python3 regex findall

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Here is my issue. Given below list:

```py
a = ['COP' , '\t\t\t', 'Basis', 'Notl', 'dv01', '6m', '9m', '1y',
     '18m', '2y', '3y', "15.6", 'mm', '4.6', '4y', '5y', '10', 'mm',
     '4.6', '6y', '7y', '8y', '9y', '10y', '20y', 'TOTAL', '\t\t9.2' ]
```

I'm trying to get some outputs like this one. The most important note is the rows
After the first number ended on "y" or "m" will come a number only if it is there in the list
Example : ('3y', '15.6', '')

SAMPLE OUTPUT ( forget about the structure that is a tuple, jsut want teh values)

```
('6m', '', '')
('9m', '', '')
('1y', '', '')
('18m', '', '')
('2y', '', '')
('3y', '15.6', '')
('4y', '', '')
('5y', '10', '')
('6y', '', '')
('7y', '', '')
('8y', '', '')
('9y', '', '')
('10y', '', '')
('20y', '', '')
```

I used the following regex that should have returned :

1. all numbers followed by "y" or "m" => (\b\d+[ym]\b)
2. and then any number (integer or not) if it appears (meaning  zero or more times)=>
   (\b[0-9]+.*[0-9]*\b)

Here is what I did, using Python3 regex and re.findall(), but still got no result

```py
rule2 = re.compile(r"(\b\d+[ym]\b)(\b[0-9]+.*[0-9]*\b)+")
a_str = " ".join(a)
OUT2 = re.findall(rule2, a_str)
print(OUT2)
# OUT2 >>[]
```

Why I'm not getting the correct result?

Comment: I think that there's a problem with \b word boundary token. You cannot chain 2 word boundary tokens.

Comment: Let me give that  try

Comment: It did not work still I removing \b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use word boundary twice. Since data is separated by non-letter/digits use `\W+` instead.

Then, escape the dot, and make it optional, or you're not going to match `10`. Don't use `.*` as it will match too much (regex greediness)

that yields more or less what you're looking for (note that matching strict numbers, integers or floats, is trickier than that, so this isn't perfect):

```
rule2 = re.compile(r"\b(\d+[ym])\W+([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)\b")
a_str = " ".join(a)
OUT2 = re.findall(rule2, a_str)
print(OUT2)

[('3y', '15.6'), ('5y', '10')]
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I'm interested in this solution because I previously saw a solution you gave to a problem. I tried to solve and I overworked it and you solved with a couple of regex !!. Since then, I have been trying to solve it and understand how you saw that solution. After 3 days I see that I failed to see the problem as just one string and that I do not have a deep knowledege or practice with Regex